# Sql Exception not handled by exception class

Tags: c#, exception, sqlexception, webexception

Its found that sometimes some web exceptions and sql Exceptions are not handled by Exception class. I know that should not happen. But on production I found that issue, unable to reproduce on my local computer.

```
try{

//some code
}
catch (Exception e){
//Sent mail and logged in db for exception
}
```

That doesn't work then I added

```
try{

//some code
}
catch (SqlException e){
//Sent mail and logged in db for exception
}
catch (Exception e){
//Sent mail and logged in db for exception
}
```

then it works fine. Is it possible in any case?

Comment: Have you considered that your mail sending and db logging code could have thrown its own exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe as follows to see where those exceptions are really coming from, because I don't believe they can bypass catch (Exception)

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
Application.ThreadException += OnThreadException;
```